# PostgreSQL - empty values that are not null and not empty strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, notnull

I ran this query on a PostgreSQL table:

```
select * wkt from table  where column <>'' and  column is not null
```

..and unexpectedly received several rows with no visible value in that column.  Why is this? Is there some 'hidden' value in that column for those rows, or a corrupted table, or something else?

Comment: i belive many value will be invisible, eg ascii 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, depends on client though

Comment: Or just spaces.

Comment: you check the first char with ascii function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t=# select ascii(chr(9));
 ascii
-------
     9
(1 row)
```

thus

```
select ascii(column) from table  where column <>'' and  column is not null
```

should give the idea

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

> ASCII code of the first character of the argument. For UTF8 returns
>   the Unicode code point of the character. For other multibyte
>   encodings, the argument must be an ASCII character.